# How to monitor Service Fabric Actors

Tags: azure-service-fabric, dynatrace, stateful-actor-service

As I understand, [Dynatrace does not support Service Fabric Actors](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/doc/appmon/application-monitoring/agents/net-agent/net-service-fabric-sensor/).

Is there an extensibility mechanism where I could add myself? For example, can I plug myself before and after every ActorProxy call, and/or before and after every method call on an Actor?

Answer (score 0):

You can build [a customized](https://github.com/Expecho/ServiceFabric-Remoting-CustomHeaders) `ActorProxy` to add logging on the caller side.

Next, you can add [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526751/5946937) into the Actor to add logging on the Actor side. Use `OnPreActorMethodAsync` and `OnPostActorMethodAsync` and some reflection to get context.

Comment: You could use the Dynatrace SDK to leverage these hooks and get to a complete PurePath. It exists for multiple technologies, including .NET. You can do distributed tracing (trace incoming/outgoing calls): https://github.com/Dynatrace/OneAgent-SDK